# How to set the warning level for every new project in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties, warning-level

as the title already mentions, i want to set a property (to be more specific: the warning level) for every newly created project to 4.

What i have done so far:
1. Opened `Property Manager->Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User`
2. Under `C/C++`: changed warning level to 4 and treat all warnings as errors
3. clicked on the save icon

This should have done it, but everytime I create a new empty project and add a new c++-file to it, when i now open the project settings: the warning level is back to the standard value (3)...
When i now open the property page again it is still set to 4 (like i want it to)...

Why does VS not apply the correct settings to my new projects?

Comment: I regret trying to answer this question, no idea what a "Generic C++ Project" might look like.  Yes, the property sheet you edited sets the default but project wizards override it.  Tinkering with these wizards is an undocumented and unsupported feature.  Post a feature request to connect.microsoft.com